# enable cors for web pages deployed within a war

Tags: java, cors, glassfish-3

Is it possible to enable CORS on the web pages that are deployed within a war?

More specifically, I have a couple of .json pages located in src/main/webapp which are packaged with my war. I can't edit their response headers in the same fashion you would with REST resources by adding response headers.

My guess is that this is something I would have to setup in the glassfish admin console but I've had no luck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding an Filter for the path you want like "/static/*.json" and set the response headers in the filter ?

Comment: Hi, my filter is setup to add the response headers to all responses (so that'll include any *.json). However, I'm under the impression that the web pages are not delivered via the same mechanisms as REST resources (I'm not to clued up on what does what in the application server itself).

Comment: Filter doesn't have to do anything with Rest services , it just simply work over the specified url paths, if u already have an filter for Cors check  ur static files path are also included in the url pattern  and check the what response headers are sent when requesting that file

Comment: Thanks for sticking it out with me Ramesh! Your comment made me realise that I was using com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters as part of my servlet configuration instead of just making a plain <filter>. That'll teach me to not post code snippets.